Inverse of pullback metric
Suppose we have the inclusion $\iota: X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ which is injective, but not a diffeomorphism. Given the standard metric $g_{\mu \overline{\nu}} dz^{\mu} \otimes d\overline{z}^{\overline{\nu}}$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$, and the dual metric given locally by the inverse $\tilde{g} = g^{\mu \bar{\nu}} \partial_{\mu} \otimes \overline{\partial}_{\bar{\nu}}$, s.t. $\tilde{g}^{\overline{b}a} g_{a \overline{c}} = \delta^{\overline{b}}_{\overline{c}}$, we define the pullback metric
$$\iota^*g = d\iota^{\alpha}_{\;\mu} g_{\alpha \overline{\beta}} \overline{d\iota^{\beta}_{\; \nu}} dZ^{\mu} \otimes d\overline{Z}^{\overline{\nu}}\in \Gamma(T^*X \otimes T^*X)$$
Is there a way to find the pullback of the dual metric '$\iota^* \tilde{g}$' on $X$ in terms of $\tilde{g}$ and the pullback Jacobians $d\iota$, without having to explicitly invert the metric $\iota^*g $ in local coordinates? I suspect the answer is no as the pullback of a contravariant tensor by a non-diffeomorphism doesn't make sense.
This is a related question  but deals with the case of a diffeomorphism.
